# Hey Guys, Probabilty Exercise.

Tags: probability

I got a Probability field with the triple like usual and P{w} is a element of the sigma algebra for all w in the sample space, I got to proof that P{w}>o for countable w element of the sample space.

Im a bit confused beacause if a event is in the sigma algebra it should be automatically >0, and that sigma algebra is defined for countable sets. Hence I think that im misinterpreting the exercise because it looks to obvious.

Comment: Automatically $>0$ or automatically $\geq 0$? There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: "*If an event is in the sigma algebra it should automatically >0*"  Wrong.  You can have probability zero events who are nonempty.  "*Sigma algebra is defined (only) for countable sets*"  Wrong.  You can have sigma algebras over uncountable sets as well.

Comment: I cant find a proper defintion for >0 events, my idea was initially to apply the definition of >0 events and to combine it with the definition of countability. I'm new at maths so please dot be to harsh :P

Comment: Is the goal "show that at most countably many singletons have positive probability"?

Comment: @Ian yeah ur right

Comment: @geetha290krm Year you are right with ≥ I missed this point.

Comment: @JMoravitz At our lecture the sigma algebra was defined for the union of countable events that are subsets of the sample space.

Comment: Let $X$ be a set (*finite, countably infinite, uncountably infinite, it doesn't matter*).  Let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the power set of $X$.  Then $\Sigma\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is called a $\sigma$-algebra if the following three things are true: 1) $X\in \Sigma$.  2) If $A\in\Sigma$ then $X\setminus A\in \Sigma$, that is it is closed under complements.  3) If $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ are a countable collection of elements of $\Sigma$, then $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup \dots$ is also an element of $\Sigma$.  This is the only place where "countable" appears in the definition.  You must have read wrong.

Comment: You can have uncountably many elements in $\Sigma$.  The events within $\Sigma$ may have uncountably many elements within them as well.  As for the probability measure, you have that if $A_1,A_2$ are disjoint events, the probability measure $\Pr(A_1\cup A_2)$ should equal $\Pr(A_1)+\Pr(A_2)$, and similarly if you have countably many disjoint $A_1,A_2,\dots$ the probability of the countable union is equal to the countable sum of the probabilities.

Comment: There are dozens of hugely important examples of uncountable sample spaces you should have been exposed to already.  Any "*continuous*" distribution for instance such as the normal distribution, the continuous uniform distribution over $(0,1)$, the Beta distribution, the chi-squared distribution, and many more.  It is well known that in these continuous distributions they satisfy the property that $\Pr(\{x\})=0$ for any individual element $x$, and your exercise here is essentially to prove that.